# How can I make XML only contain tags for child classes when working with JAXB?

Tags: inheritance, jaxb

I have some Java classes extending a common superclass. I would like to marshal/unmarshal them with JAXB without seeing a superclass tag in the XML representation. The module containing the superclass does not know about the subclasses that are available in the current context.

Here is a minimal example of what I am trying to do, and of my approach:

Example XML:

```xml
<root>
   <instance>
       <member>foo</member>
   </instance>
</root>
```

This should be an equivalent Java representation, where `Root` has a member of type `Superclass`, which is a parent of `Instance`:

```java
Root root = new Root();
Instance instance = new Instance();
instance.setMember("foo");
root.setSuperclass(instance);
```

My main concern is to go from the XML representation to Java objects. Note that I explicitly do not want to write the superclass tag in the XML file, so something along the lines of `<superclass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="instance">` is no option for me.

My current implementation:

```java
@XmlRootElement
class Root {
    private Superclass superclass;

    @XmlAnyElement
    Superclass getSuperclass() { return superclass; }
    void setSuperclass(Superclass superclass) { this.superclass = superclass; }
}

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ValueAdapter.class)
class Superclass {}

@XmlRootElement(name = "instance")
class Instance extends Superclass {
    private String member;

    @XmlElement
    public String getMember() {return member;}
    public void setMember(String member) {this.member = member;}
}

class ValueAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Object, Superclass> {
    @Override
    public Object marshal(Superclass v) {
        return v;
    }
    @Override
    public Superclass unmarshal(Object v) {
        Element element = (Element) v;
        if (element.getNodeName().equals("instance")) {
            Instance instance = new Instance();
            instance.setMember(element.getTextContent());
            return instance;
        }
        else throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

In the example, I hardcoded the `unmarshal` method for `Instance`, but later it will access a service where multiple subclasses can register.

The approach above kind of works, but it looks completely wrong. Manually unmarshalling the subclass object by looking deep into the Node is really ugly. After all, am I not using JAXB to hide exactly such XML tree traversal? It becomes even worse if the subclass has multiple members which are more complex than pure strings.
I'm quite new to JAXB, so I assume that I am either mistreating the framework or overlooking something obvious. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a reasonable solution after all. The idea is to actually let JAXB continue to do its magic, but starting with the instance as the new root element:

```java
    public Superclass unmarshal(Object v) throws JAXBException {
        Element element = (Element) v;

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Instance.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        return unmarshaller.unmarshal(element, Instance.class).getValue();
    }
```

Of course, the costly creation of a new context should in the real application not be redone every time, but the context will be supplied externally by a provider that knows about all the available instances, like this:

```java
    public Superclass unmarshal(Object v) throws JAXBException {
        Element element = (Element) v;
        String tag = element.getNodeName();

        Class<? extends Superclass> clazz = instanceProvider.getClassForXmlTag(tag);
        JAXBContext jc = instanceProvider.getJaxbContextForXmlTag(tag);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        return unmarshaller.unmarshal(element, clazz).getValue();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is an even simpler solution without any manual intervention, namely `@XmlElementRef`:

```
@XmlRootElement
class Root {
    private Superclass superclass;

    @XmlElementRef
    Superclass getSuperclass() { return superclass; }
    void setSuperclass(Superclass superclass) { this.superclass = superclass; }
}
```

`Superclass` does then not need any annotation whatsoever, and in particular no converter.